# How to fill the matrix A associated with an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, quadratics

I am solving some of the problems given in Gilbert Strag's **Introduction to Linear Algebra** book in chapter 6. I came across one of the problems which couldn't solve. So I thought I should ask you guys how you would go for solving it. Below I post a picture taken of the problem taken from the book.

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/10ym5hw.png]

Could you please tell me how would you fill the entries in the matrix A?

Thank you

Comment: Fill in $A$ with nine letters (variables). Then compute the two sides and get equations on the variables to solve. It would be a good idea to import the picture here so nobody has to follow the link.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I couldn't import the picture here since I don't have a reputation of 10 or more ...

Comment: Should we assume that $A$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite your problem with a bit less indices in the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=4(x-y+2z)^2
$$
calculating the left side you find:
$$
x(a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)+y(b_1x+b_2y+b_3z)+z(c_1x+c_2y+c_3z)=4(x-y+2z)^2
$$
So you have two plynomials in $x,y,z$ that have to be equals for all $(x,y,z)$ and this is true only if all the coefficents of the monomials are the same, so you can write a system of equations and find the unknowns $a_i,b_i,c_i$.

Comment: I did not have enough reputation to upvote your post. I just did it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Expand the right-hand side to get:

$$ 4 x_1^2-8 x_2 x_1+16 x_3 x_1+4 x_2^2+16 x_3^2-16 x_2 x_3 $$

If we take $A$ to be symmetric, it is well known that the entry $a_{ij} = a_{ji} $ of the matrix $A$ is equal to half the coefficient of $x_i x_j$ if $i \neq j$ and the coefficient of $x_i^2$ otherwise. Namely:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & -4 & 8 \\
-4 & 4 & -8 \\
8 & -8 & 16  \end{bmatrix} $$